# MPAndroidChart - Horizontal bar chart - how to align x axis label to left align, align bar value to left on negative bar chart

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I'm new to MPAndroidChart, here I have some issue with the horizontal bar chart

1.**How to align x-axis label to the left**

2.**How to align bar chart value to the left side of the bar for negative numbers**

3.**How to avoid gap where x-y axis meet when axis line with is more**

4.**How to fix bar overlapping on top of axis line when zooming**

[image]

[image]

Here is my code

```
HorizontalBarChart mStatGraph = (HorizontalBarChart) findViewById(R.id.reportlist_stat_graph);
    mStatGraph.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    mStatGraph.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
    mStatGraph.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    mStatGraph.setMaxVisibleValueCount(20);
    mStatGraph.setPinchZoom(false);
    mStatGraph.setDrawGridBackground(true);
    mStatGraph.setGridBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    mStatGraph.setExtraBottomOffset(20);
    mStatGraph.setViewPortOffsets(5, 0, 5, 20);

    XAxis xl = mStatGraph.getXAxis();
    xl.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xl.setTypeface(mTfLight);
    xl.setTextSize(13f);
    xl.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2C3846"));
    xl.setAxisLineColor(Color.BLACK);
    xl.setAxisLineWidth(2f);
    xl.setDrawAxisLine(true);
    xl.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xl.setDrawLabels(true);
    xl.setGranularity(1f);
    xl.setAxisMinimum(0f);
    xl.setYOffset(2f);
    xl.setXOffset(10f);
    xl.setSpaceMin(2f);
    int lineChartXOffset = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.report_bar_chart_xoffset);
    xl.setXOffset(lineChartXOffset);
    mStatGraph.getRendererXAxis().getPaintAxisLabels().setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);


    YAxis yl = mStatGraph.getAxisLeft();
    yl.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    yl.setAxisLineWidth(0f);
    yl.setAxisLineWidth(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    yl.setDrawLabels(false);
    yl.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);
    yl.setDrawGridLines(true);
    yl.setAxisMinimum(-0.005f);
    yl.setSpaceBottom(5f);
    yl.setSpaceTop(5f);
    yl.setEnabled(true);

    YAxis yr = mStatGraph.getAxisRight();
    yr.setTypeface(mTfLight);
    yr.setTextSize(12f);
    yr.setDrawGridLines(false);
    yr.setDrawLabels(true);
    yr.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);
    yr.setAxisMinimum(-0.005f);
    yr.setXOffset(15f);
    yr.setYOffset(-3f);
    yr.setDrawAxisLine(true);
    yr.setAxisLineColor(Color.BLACK);
    yr.setAxisLineWidth(2f);
    yr.setSpaceBottom(5f);
    yr.setSpaceTop(5f);
    yr.setEnabled(true);
    yr.setValueFormatter(barGraphValueFormatter);

    mStatGraph.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    setData();
    mStatGraph.setFitBars(true);
    mStatGraph.invalidate();
```

Please help me fix those issues.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like you have four different questions that are not related to each other. Please ask them separately

Comment: I've asked a question about changing the alignment of Y-axis labels to the left here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60654471/mpandroidchart-how-to-change-the-alignment-of-y-axis-labels

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the first question

1. Add into x axis labels

```
align: 'left', reserveSpace: true
```

Comment: where did you find these? i cant see any mention of them in the docs